# connecting a domain name to a ip:port

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, dns

so currently I have a registered domain name
I also have a docker imgage running but to connect it i have to connect through port 81 instead of 80 (thanks ISP)

so in order to connect I have to go through http://x.x.x.x:81   is there a way to make it so [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)  can connect to x.x.x.x:81  with port 81

I tried looking around but couldn't seem to find anything

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such was as this is not how DNS works. DNS will only resolve to your IP address `x.x.x.x`, not its port. So you have to use:

```
http://www.example.com:81
```

Comment: so is the only way for other people to access the webpage is by using my ip:81 ?

Comment: @Agnias Yes, if you are not using default ports of 80 or 443.

Comment: oh i didn't know you could add :81 to the end of a domain name that should actually work perfectly fine. just didn't want people to have to connect with ip and wanted to put to use the domain i had registered. thanks for all the info

Comment: @Agnias No problem. If that helps, accepting the answer would be appreciated.